# "await Task.Delay(ms);" exits while loop

Tags: c#, loops

I use a while loop to change the colors of a LED. I want to wait 1 second between color changes and keep the UI from freezing. If I use await it seems to just exit the loop. How else can I do this?

I tried creating an outside method `Wait()` and calling it in the while loop. This keeps the loop from exiting but it also doesn't wait for the 1 second and changes the colors instantly. Flag is a global variable triggered by a button on another form.

```
private async void LEDLights(int Device)
{
    Flag = false;

    if (Device == 1)
    {
        while (Flag == false)
        {
            //Change LED Colors
            ChangeLED(Red);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            ChangeLED(Blue);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            ChangeLED(Green);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }

    Flag = false;
}
```

What I'm expecting to happen is the while loop waits 1 second between color changes and meanwhile not freezes the UI so I can stop the loop when I want.
I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: how is `LEDLights` called?

Comment: You have an async void method. Unless this is an event handler (and it doesn't appear to be) that's going to be an issue. See [Async/Await Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Only return `void` from an async method when its an event handler.  Otherwise, it should at least return `Task`.

Comment: Async void is basically fire and forget; you can't await this method unless you return a task

Comment: also async != multithreading

Comment: One of the issues with async-void methods is that they swallow errors since no one is listening for them to complete. My suspicion is that the ChangeLED method is throwing an error which is causing it to exit the loop.

Comment: @EricDamtoft this should cause the app to crash if called on the UI thread

Comment: Oh yeah that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. All three of your comments were helpful. By changing LEDLights to a task and calling it with "await LEDLights(1);" it works now. Thanks.

```
    private async Task LEDLights(int Device)
    {
        Flag = false;
        if (Device == 1)
        {
            while (Flag == false)
            {
                //Change LED Colors
                ChangeLED(Red);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                ChangeLED(Blue);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                ChangeLED(Green);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
        Flag = false;
    }
    //called with "await LEDLights(1);"
```

Comment: I would've selected one of the comments as an answer but I'm new to the community and don't know how/if possible

Comment: Comments cannot be selected as an answer.  Typically when an answer is in the comments, we aren't sure, or don't feel like taking the time to write up a complete, quality answer.  In such cases, citing the appropriate person in your answer is generally sufficient, but not "required".